# MVC View Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, inheritance

For Example:
Let's say that I want to return a **view** that displays a list of cars and also show a section of dealers in your area.  These are two disjointed pieces of data.

My **view** inherits a list of cars like the following:

```
public partial class CarLot : ViewPage<List<Cars>>
{

}
```

Now from the **controller** I can return the **view** like the following:

```
return View(Model.GetCars());
```

To render this, my markup would look something like the following:

```
<% foreach (Car myCar in ViewData.Model)
{some html here}
%>
```

This takes care of the list of cars, but my question is, how do I handle the list of dealers?  Does the **view** support multiple inheritance or am I going to have to hit the **model** again form the markup?  I know it can be done that way, but am not sure if it is the best practice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a data transfer object

```
public class CarLotViewModel
{
     public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
     public List<Dealer> NearbyDealers { get; set; }
}
```

Set your view to use the view model:

```
public partial class CarLot : ViewPage<CarLotViewModel>
{    
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var model = new CarLotViewModel();

model.Cars = GetCars();
model.NearbyDealers = GetDealers();

return View(model);
```

Then enumerate each collection in your view:

```
<% foreach (Car car in ViewData.Model.Cars) { %>
....
<% foreach (Dealer dealer in ViewData.Model.NearbyDealers) { %>
```

Comment: is public partial class CarLot : ViewPage<CarLotViewModel>
{} is equivalent to @model CarLotViewModel ?

Answer (score 0):

> Set your view to use the view model:
>
> public partial class CarLot :
>   ViewPage {     }

There is no code-behind in MVC 1.0. How do you set the view to use view model?

Comment: It's a ASPX. Code-behind is allowed, although discouraged because it violates the ideals of separating Controller and View.

Comment: Well, I dont use the code behind.  But in Preview and Beta, the ViewPage inheritance defaulted to the code behind page.  Now, for a strongly typed View it occurs in the markup.  In Release 1.0 it would look like this: Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CarLotViewModel>" in the page markup.